# Create roles with UI interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm new working with asp.net core 2 and I'm trying to add a view to create Roles in a webpage, so my method is something like:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole(ApplicationRoleModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var role in model.RoleList)
                {
                    var roleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name);
                    if (roleExists) continue;
                    var createRole = _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                }
                foreach (var item in model.RoleClaimList)
                {
                    var currentClaimList = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(item.Role);
                    var needToAddClaims = currentClaimList.Except(item.ClaimList);
                    var needToRemoveClaims = item.ClaimList.Except(currentClaimList);
                    foreach (var claim in needToAddClaims)
                    {
                        await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(item.Role, claim);
                    }
                    foreach (var claim in needToRemoveClaims)
                    {
                        await _roleManager.RemoveClaimAsync(item.Role, claim);
                    }
                }
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

`ApplicationRoleModel` model

```
public class ApplicationRoleModel : ClaimsToRoleModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<ApplicationRole> RoleList { get; set; }
    }
```

`ClaimsToRoleModel` model

```
public class ClaimsToRoleModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<RoleClaimModel> RoleClaimList { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleClaimModel
    {
        public ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Claim> ClaimList { get; set; }
    }
```

So I create a view like:

```
@page
@model Security.Dto.Models.ApplicationRoleModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create New Role";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-controller="security" asp-action="createrole" method="post">
            <h4>Create new Role.</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name">Name</label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

But when I try to build project it returns

> 'ApplicationRoleModel' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no
>   extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ApplicationRoleModel' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

How is supposed to be my view in order to respond to my models? I'm really confusted there. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your view, you have referenced a form property that does not exist, hence the error.

In the first line of your view, you have declared a model of type `ApplicationRoleModel` and in your form you have declared an input for a 'Name' property that does not exist on that model.

To resolve, the issue, you might add a `Name` property to `ApplicationRoleModel` - though I'd use `NewRoleName` to be clearer:

```
public class ApplicationRoleModel : ClaimsToRoleModel
{
    [BindNever] // BindNever is to avoid model-binding security issues
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationRole> RoleList { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Name" )] // This will be displayed in the `<label asp-for>` element
    public String NewRoleName { get; }
}
```

In your cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Name" />
    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
 </div>
```

If you want to allow multiple items to be edited, change your view-model to use `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` and use a `for( Int32 i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )` loop (you cannot use `foreach` for this), like so:

```
public class NewRoleViewModel
{
    //[Required] // no-longer required so that users can submit empty lists
    [Display(Name="Name" )]
    public String NewRoleName { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRoleModel : ClaimsToRoleModel
{
    [BindNever] // BindNever is to avoid model-binding security issues
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationRole> RoleList { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<NewRoleViewModel> NewRoles { get; } = new List<NewRoleViewModel>();
}
```

In your cshtml:

```
@for( Int32 i = 0; i < this.Model.NewRoles.Count; i++ ) {
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="NewRoles[i].Name" />
        <input asp-for="NewRoles[i].Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
}
```

Note that the `NewRoles` list will be empty by default, you will need to add some empty entries in your Controller action method:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ApplicationRoleModel vm = new ApplicationRoleModel();
    vm.NewRoles.Add( new NewRoleViewModel() );
    vm.NewRoles.Add( new NewRoleViewModel() );
    vm.NewRoles.Add( new NewRoleViewModel() );

    return this.View( vm );
}
```

Comment: Nice!, what about nested model. For example in second foreach I use `item.Role`, `item.ClaimList`, how should I use in view, if I only can call one model in a single view?

Comment: @Jonathan I've amended my answer with instructions on how to perform ASP.NET view-model binding with collections.